# ThinkPad T420 hangs on boot - graphics driver issue?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I start my laptop up and it hangs during boot at

```
ACPI: Video Device [VID1] (multi-head:yes rom:yes post:no)
```

I've already tried setting the kernel boot parameter `nox2apic`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nox2apic"
```

but it slows the system way down and I can't play my steam games. Would installing drivers other than the nouveau drivers fix the problem and speed it back up?

My machine is a ThinkPad T420 running 16.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: not a dupe of that pilot6

Comment: @JeffyJefferson: Why is it not a duplicate of the question linked by Pilot6? Did you try its (applicable) answers? What happened for each of them when you did?

Comment: Could you please try some of the other answers in the linked question? The `nomodeset` option is very promising in general. Which graphics adapters does the computer in question have, i. e. what's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA`?